# fuse 6.3 container-list command thrown nullpointerexception

Tags: jbossfuse, fuseesb, fabric8

In fabric ensemble setup, one fuse server has joined successfully using fabric:join command.

After that if we run container-list command it throws below error and in cli it displayed "error executing command: java.lang.nullpointerexception".

(log file)
io.fabric8.api.FabricException: org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException$NoNodeException: KeeperErrorCode = NoNode for /fabric/authentication/crypt/algorithm

Comment: does it happen in the container that joined the ensemble? or in the other containers that were part of the ensemble before the join?

Comment: Thanks for replay,it is not happened in Fabric(ensemble) Server with a registry service installed containers   and it happened on the container being added (or joined)to a fabric from other server. yes the containers are already part of the ensemble. when I run fabric:join command it says "the container already joined(part) of fabric

Comment: which exactly Fuse 6.3 version are you using?

Comment: jboss-fuse-6.3.0.redhat-187

Comment: 6.3.0.GA had issues with joining fabric, when default version was no longer available. Since then, several issues related to ensemble joining/leaving were resolved. What does `container-list` show on the working container?

Comment: it shows both ensemble server and joined server containers. Let me know is there a way to remove joined server containers details from list(or from fabric server).

Comment: the `container-list` output shows containers that wrote their entries to zookeeper. Newer versions of Fuse 6.3.0 (R13) has `fabric:leave` command that cleans all the entries. For now, you could simply use `fabric:container-delete --force` on this failed container and then try joining again.